# Ошибка связанная с gson.fromjson

Tags: android, post, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

Я пишу приложение на `retrofit`, приложение использует `api-yandex` для перевода слов.
Одно слово или предложение с запятыми, но без пробелов, он переводит спокойно.
Но если в запросе появится предложение в котором есть запятые, то приложение крашится, почему?
Ошибка в строке, где `gson.fromjson`.

```
        try {
            Response<Object> response = call.execute();

            if (response != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(response.body()));
                Type stringStringMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
                Log.e(TAG,"test");
                String jsonResponse = String.valueOf(response.body());
                Log.e(TAG,"test2");
                Map<String,String> map = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, Map.class);
                Log.e(TAG,"test3");
                for(Map.Entry e: map.entrySet()){
                    Log.e(TAG,e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
                    translated = String.valueOf(e.getValue());

                }
                Log.e(TAG,"end test");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Вот ошибка

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
>                                                                              Process: com.example.notdi.imgfinder, PID: 3640
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                                  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                                  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                               Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at
>   line 1 column 39 path $.[1]
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:902)
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.notdi.imgfinder.MainActivity$MainTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:127)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.notdi.imgfinder.MainActivity$MainTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                               Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated
>   array at line 1 column 39 path $.[1]
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559)
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:476)
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:414)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.read(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:60)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) 
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801) 
>                                                                                  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.notdi.imgfinder.MainActivity$MainTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:127) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.notdi.imgfinder.MainActivity$MainTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) 
>                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Приведите пример содержимого `response.body()`, с которым не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гуляя по всем форумам в итоге 2-3 дня, разобрался. AsyncTask не рекомендуют использоваться (но думаю что можно), главная проблема в том, что не используется класс сериализации, по каким то причинам retrofit заточен работать именно так.

Пример класса сериализации:

```
public class Translate {
    private int code;
    private String lang;
    private ArrayList<String> text;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(ArrayList<String> text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@woesss
столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой в том же упражнении
задаю перевести "мама мыла раму"(кавычки добавлены мной)

> response.body() = {code=200.0, lang=ru-en, text=[mom soap frame]}